# Simulate auto registration of device under the gateway using Node Red editor?

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, node-red, watson-iot

We are able to create device and gateway using Watson IOT platform service but there is no option to attach device under a gateway. We know there is an API to manually register device under the gateway . But is there a way to simulate auto register of a new device under the gateway in node red flow editor?

Also, need clarification on this,

1.Able to simulate event for device and gateway separately but is there a way to simulate event for a device which is attached to the gateway ? also how can we identify the event is from device or gateway.

2.How can simulate and differentiate QoS of messages published on a topic? I've set MQTT nodes with different priorities like 0,1,2 but unable to differentiate?

3.Can we publish commands to device or gateway using MQTT node? I read many tutorials they were using Watson IOT node.

Comment: Have you looked at recipes related to device simulators, e.g. https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/ti-sensor-tag-simulator/ and https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/create-a-iot-simulator-of-any-iot-device-mqtt/#r_ingredients these can now use the device simulator nodes. 2. You can use actions to send commands to devices/gateways. 3. An application can publish actions to a device/gateway - have you looked at the IoT Platform documentation e.g. https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/mqtt/index.htmlBasically, read the recipes and docs.

Comment: Thanks for the response @barny Let me try

Comment: Were you able to get this working using the advice provided by barny?